# As tags "gerência-de-projeto" e "gerenciamento-de-projetos" devem ser mescladas?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica, tags-sinônimas

Reparei que temos duas tags parecidas: [gerência-de-projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ger%c3%aancia-de-projeto) e [gerenciamento-de-projetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerenciamento-de-projetos). Me parece se tratar da mesma coisa. Há poucas perguntas em cada uma delas (aliás, eu próprio as utilizei de forma inconsistente antes de me dar conta da duplicidade), de modo que seria simples nesse momento eliminar uma (se esse for o melhor curso de ação).

O que fazemos? Marcamos como sinônimos? Retageamos e eliminamos uma? Qual? Minha inclinação está em manter a [gerência-de-projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ger%c3%aancia-de-projeto) (ou talvez criar uma [gestão-de-projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gest%c3%a3o-de-projeto), pois a palavra "gestão" me soa melhor), mas gostaria de ouvir a opinião da comunidade (em particular dos que falam pt_PT).

Comment: Creio que deveriam deixar apenas uma delas, é a mesma coisa para [tag:server] e [tag:servidor].

Comment: Concordo com deixar apenas gestão-de-projeto

Answer (score 4):

Estive pensando sobre o assunto. Analisando algumas fontes na web, entre elas a [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger%C3%AAncia_de_projetos), vi que os termos apresentados são usados como sinônimos com uso um pouco variado entre diferentes grupos e regiões, mas também há muitos que fazem uma [clara distinção](http://webinsider.com.br/2010/04/03/definicao-de-gestao-administracao-e-gerenciamento/).

Também notei que o termo *gestão de projetos* é usado pela quase totalidade dos cursos de MBA e graduação em geral.

Mas qual seria uma fonte relativamente confiável para obter o termo mais usado? Pensei no [PMBOK](http://brasil.pmi.org/brazil/PMBOKGuideAndStandards/PMBOKemPortugues.aspx) ou em [algum site de PMI](http://brasil.pmi.org/brazil/AboutUS/WhatIsProjectManagement.aspx). Ambos usam *gerenciamento de projetos*.

Com base nisso, creio que o mais indicado para ser a *tag* principal é [gerenciamento-de-projetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerenciamento-de-projetos). Os outros seriam sinônimos.

Alguém discorda?

Comment: Eu gosto mais de "gestão" por lembrar menos do cargo de "gerente".

Comment: @bfavaretto Tenho que concordar. Só tenho medo de ser impreciso. Não tem ninguém com certificação PMI aqui no site?

Comment: Gestão e gerenciamento são sim a mesma coisa. A diferença é que algumas pessoas gostam de palavras grandes. Por mim podemos manter a maior por motivo de ser a mais comum, mas sinceramente, tanto faz.

Comment: De fato, parece ser tudo a mesma coisa... [Segundo a Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger%C3%AAncia_de_projetos), "gestão" é mais usada no português europeu, "gerência" no português brasileiro, e "gerenciamento" ou "administração" seriam variantes. Pessoalmente, usei "gerenciamento" a vida toda, somente após conviver com meu sócio atual (que é formado em Administração) passei a ouvir e em seguida usar a palavra "gestão". Hoje esta me soa melhor, mas tenho consciência de que isso é 100% subjetivo...

Comment: Eu acho que quando alguém de Administração fala de "gestão" talvez esteja querendo incluir o papel do gestor. No nosso escopo, o que nos interessa é mais o processo, então também me parece "gerenciamento" faz mais sentido. Vide a minha resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Pra ajudar (ou talvez atrapalhar hahaha). :)

### Definições no Dicionário

<sup>Fonte: [Grande Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/)</sup>

> **gerência**
>
> ```
> substantivo feminino
> 1 ação ou efeito de gerir; gerenciamento
>     ‹ g. doméstica ›
> 2 função ou exercício de gerente; administração, gestão
> 3 jur. mandato convencional ou contratual pelo qual alguém é investido na posição
> de administrador dos negócios de uma sociedade, com poderes para cumprir os
> objetivos do contrato social
> 4 indivíduo ou conjunto de indivíduos investidos nessa função ou mandato
>     ‹ cabe à g. determinar as novas regras contratuais ›
> 5 p.met. espaço em que esse(s) indivíduo(s) trabalha(m)
>     ‹ a g. foi dedetizada ontem ›
> ```
>
> **gestão**
>
> ```
> substantivo feminino
> 1 ato ou efeito de gerir; administração, gerência
> 2 mandato político
>     ‹ este cais foi construído na primeira g. do atual prefeito ›
> ```
>
> **gerenciamento**
>
> ```
> substantivo masculino
> ação ou efeito de gerenciar; gerência
> ```

### Resultados no Google

- `"Gestão de Projetos"`: **718 mil** resultados
- `"Gerência de Projetos"`: mais de **8 milhões** de resultados
- `"Gerenciamento de Projetos"`: **641 mil** resultados

**Gráfico de Interesse**<sup>[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22Gest%C3%A3o%20de%20Projetos%22%2C%20%22Ger%C3%AAncia%20de%20Projetos%22%2C%20%22Gerenciamento%20de%20Projetos%22&cmpt=q)</sup>
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Minha Interpretação

O termo "gerência" claramente também inclui o cargo ou posição dentro da empresa (e provavelmente por isso tenha um número muito maior de retornos nas buscas do Google). Os demais termos são mais facilmente intercambiáveis, muito embora "gestão" também possa significar o cargo ou posição. Entre "gestão" e "gerenciamento", talvez "gestão" seja mais empregada por ser mais curta (lei do mínimo esforço), muito embora "gerenciamento pareça levemente mais popular em pesquisas.

Mas, considerando que o escopo do SOPT está mais preocupado com o processo e não com o cargo, eu acho que a escolha por "gerenciamento" parece mesmo mais apropriada (e condizente com a [observação do @utluiz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1712/73) de que "Gerenciamento de Projetos" é mais usado nas certificações).

Cabe lembrar que isso parece fazer sentido em português do Brasil (eu só consultei o Houaiss), mas não necessariamente em outros paises falantes de português. Seria importante ter a opinião (ou confirmação) de alguém que não seja do Brasil.