# Quais os critérios para uma tag deixar de existir?

Tags: suporte, tags

De vez em quando me deparo com uma tag ou outra e me pergunto se ela deveria ou não existir. Pesquisei aqui no Meta e não encontrei uma pergunta explicando sobre, então fui à *Central de ajuda*:

- [O que são tags e como devo usá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

> Uma tag é uma palavra ou frase que descreve o tópico da pergunta (...) classificando as perguntas em categorias específicas e bem definidas.

- [Quando devo criar novas tags?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

> As tags mais comuns já existem em um site maduro. Você deve sempre dar preferência às tags existentes; só crie novas tags quando achar que sua pergunta realmente trata de um tópico novo sobre o qual ninguém nunca fez perguntas neste site.

---

As dúvidas que tenho e que não consegui encontrar a resposta são:

- Como identificar uma tag que não deveria existir? Existem critérios bem definidos para isso ou é algo um pouco mais subjetivo?
- As tags são removidas automaticamente apenas se não estiverem associadas à uma pergunta ou existe outra situação?

Essas dúvidas me vieram à mente pois vi a tag [semver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semver), com apenas 4 perguntas (1 fechada e 1 sem resposta) e me pareceu fazer sentido removê-la, pois não consegui imaginar quando usá-la faria sentido - o fragmento de wiki não explica quando utilizar, e temos a tag [versionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versionamento), que é diferente porém similar.

Também vi a nova tag [svelte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svelte), que apesar de ter apenas [uma questão no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=svelte) sobre Svelte, me parece fazer sentido existir, já que Svelte é algo como o Angular, React e Vue, eventualmente a tag pode se tornar mais ativa. Na [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/293114), a edição que resultou na criação dessa tag teve duas rejeições e duas aceitações.

OBS: Quando digo "remover uma tag" (como no exemplo da [semver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semver)), quero dizer "removê-la das perguntas para que posteriormente a tag seja excluída".

Comment: A remoção da tag é feita quando não associada a nenhuma pergunta e é uma checagem periodicia dentro do proprio sistema, não é feito de forma manual e nem por pessoas.

Comment: Certo. Esse detalhe eu sabia (segundo bullet), só não sabia se era o único caso. Adicionei uma OBS à pergunta para deixar mais claro o que quero dizer com "remover uma tag" nos outros parágrafos.

Comment: Basicamente a comunidade deve chegar a um consenso de que ela deveria não existir, que elas traz mais problemas que vantagens. Ter poucas perguntas não é um critério. Se a tag ajuda classificar o conteúdo ela deve existir, mesmo para 2 perguntas. E deve haver ação. Já houveram propostas de remoção que não teve ação.

Comment: "...comunidade deve chegar a um consenso de que ela deveria não existir..." [exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=primaverabss+is%3Aquestion), não é um processo simples, há muito debate antes de excluir uma tag.

Comment: No SOen tem [este FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070). Não tem um equivalente no nosso, mas acredito que os mesmos critérios se aplicam. O problema é que tem alguns que são meio subjetivos ("*A tag adiciona alguma informação significativa à postagem?*") e outros nem tanto ("*Ela significa a mesma coisa em todos os contextos comuns?*"), então no fim vai ter que discutir aqui no meta mesmo, para se chegar ao já mencionado consenso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quando uma tag é removida?

Como mencionado nos comentários da pergunta, as tags são removidas apenas se não estiverem associadas à alguma pergunta. Isso é um procedimento automático do sistema ([*Roomba*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314065/818993)) que é feito [diariamente às 03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/818993).

## Quando devemos remover uma tag?

De forma geral, a remoção de uma tag deve ser consenso da comunidade. Crie uma pergunta aqui no Meta sobre, pode-se usar as tags [debate](/questions/tagged/debate) e [tag-específica](/questions/tagged/tag-espec%c3%adfica).

Abaixo seguem alguns fatores que são usados no [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/8839059) e no [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/818993) antes de sugerir um debate sobre a exclusão de uma tag.

### Os quatro critérios

**1) A tag descreve o conteúdo das perguntas às quais se aplica? E é não-ambíguo?**

Veja por exemplo a tag [codificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Ela não existe mais e [houve um debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7288/100416) para isso. Em resumo, a palavra *codificação* estava sendo interpretada para diferentes situações, sendo assim uma tag ambígua. [Algo similar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5176/100416) ocorreu com a [desenvolvimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desenvolvimento), que claramente não descreve o conteúdo da pergunta.

**2) O conceito descrito está mesmo dentro do escopo do site?**

Não faz sentido termos uma tag [infraestrutura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infraestrutura) se isso fugiria do [escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Foi o que aconteceu com a tag [debate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate) [nesta discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4579/100416).

**3) A tag adiciona alguma informação significativa à publicação?**

Se você está em dúvida se uma tag é útil ou não, dê uma olhada nas principais tags relacionadas (ao lado direito na página da tag) e veja as perguntas que possuem essa tag. Se alguma dessas tags forem sinônimos, elas deveriam ser mescladas e se tornarem de fato [sinônimos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). Isso aconteceu com as tags [gerência-de-projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ger%c3%aancia-de-projeto) e [gerenciamento-de-projetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerenciamento-de-projetos), por exemplo (veja [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/100416)).

Se não há nenhum sinônimo ali, veja as perguntas que possuem essa tag. Se ela é mais mal utilizada do que bem, pode ser o caso de melhorar a sua recomendação de uso (fragmento de tag) ou mesmo trazer o debate aqui para o Meta.

Note que também vale a pena verificar o número de seguidores da tag: se um grupo considerável de pessoas está usando uma determinada tag para encontrar questões nas quais estão interessadas, então talvez você tenha perdido algo importante ao avaliar seu valor no contexto.

**4) Essa tag significa a mesma coisa em todos os contextos comuns?**

Isso está relacionado ao ponto 1, sobre ambiguidade. Aconteceu com a tag [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap), que não pode ser mais utilizada hoje por causa dos seus diferentes significados de acordo com o contexto ([Qual deve ser o uso correto da tag "bootstrap"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/100416) e [Vamos arrumar a tag bootstrap](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6472/100416)). O fragmento de wiki da tag foi atualizado de acordo para orientar os usuários que tentarem utilizá-la.

### Quando posso começar a remover as tags ruins?

Uma vez que a tag atenda aos critérios anteriores, uma discussão deve ser feita no Meta para entrar num [consenso da comunidade e documentar a decisão](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356963/8839059). Isto é importante porque:

1. Pode haver uma decisão de limpar a tag, porém ninguém realizar
2. Pode haver a limpeza e a tag voltar
3. Pode ocorrer o debate mas não a conclusão
4. Pode concluir-se que a tag é útil

E caso você se depare com uma tag que questiona se é útil ou não, pode encontrá-la já num debate do Meta e entender qual foi o consenso sobre ela.

O Meta SE / SO possui uma política de que, caso a tag possua menos de 50 perguntas, você tenha um conhecimento reconhecido (i.e. ao menos uma medalha de bronze) de todas as tecnologias relevantes para a tag e tiver conversado com pelo menos um outro [membro confiável da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), você pode prosseguir e removê-la sozinho ou com uma pequena ajuda, sem a necessidade de criar uma discussão no Meta.

Acredito que podemos adaptar isso para algo em torno de 20 perguntas aqui, já que a nossa comunidade é menor. Caso a tag não se encaixe nestas especificações, o debate no Meta deve ocorrer antes de uma ação de limpeza.

As tags ruins costumam ser consequências de perguntas ruins. Portanto, se você está prestes a remover uma tag incorreta, comece removendo as perguntas incorretas com esta tag: encontre as perguntas fechadas e exclua-as, encontre as perguntas com votos negativos e feche-as (se forem votos justos), encontre as perguntas mal escritas e reescreva-as (se elas merecerem). Após isso, pode-se começar a remover a tag.

**Atenção:** não se preocupe com isso a menos que você tenha [todos os direitos de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), pois uma edição sugerida precisaria da aprovação de 2 usuários com esse privilégio de edição, tornando o processo mais exaustivo.

Comment: Tentei trazer um compilado das informações que encontrei no Meta SE, Meta SO, nos comentários daqui e nas discussões que li sobre tags específicas neste Meta. Caso percebam que deixei algo passar ou que há alguma inconsistência, avisem por favor :)